# Java - Recursion

Tags: java

The following is my adaptation of an AP Computer Science question.
The book says it should print 00100123
I think it should print 0010012
But the code below actually prints 3132123

What is going on?
Also it does not appear to have any stop condition?!

```
public class Mystery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        n = 3;
        mystery(n);
    }

    public static void mystery(int n) {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            mystery(k);
            System.out.print(n);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual question reads:
Consider the following method.

```
public void mystery (int n)
{
     int k;
     for (k=0 ; k < n ; k++)
     {
          mystery(k);
          System.out.print(n);
     }
}
```

What value is returned by the call mystery (3)?

I now understand that the loop forms the stop condition and I think I understand jhamon's comment "last instruction is to print n. n is 3, there is no way it prints only '0010012'" but I don't understand why the book says it should print 00100123.

As Batsheba says I have tried watching the variables while debugging but the book says it should print 00100123. **Thanks very much jhamon for the corrected code**, so from what I can see the book is wrong?

Comment: last instruction is to print `n`. `n`is 3, there is no way it prints only '0010012'

Comment: `Also it does not appear to have any stop condition?!` It has one: `k<n` in the `for` loop. Can you also post the question you are trying to solve?

Comment: `k<n` becomes the stop condition. In fact, the whole thing is obvious if you use a line by line debugger, or run the code logically in your head.

Comment: hint: the `print` is not at the right place, try to move it out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

That program cannot print "0". It prints `n`, and if `n` is 0 it will never reach the `System.out.print(n)` line. That line is inside the `for` statment with `k<n`.

As others have pointed out in the comments, that condition in the `for` loop is also the stop condition. `mystery` will recursively call itself `n` times. However, in each of these calls, the parameter is smaller.
(For fun, try changing the condition to `k <= n`. Then it will not terminate, because the parameter is smaller *or equal*).

If you change the line to `print(k)`, which is what was probably intended, it will indeed print "0010012".
Here is an [ideone link](http://ideone.com/5N7utU) to show that.

Comment: put the print outside the lop and you get the result given by the book. Here is a fork of your ideone [http://ideone.com/1s1YYt](http://ideone.com/1s1YYt)

Comment: @jhamon Good find! BTW you should edit the comment. There's a ")" where there should be a "]", breaking the link.